# Implementing a Set in Java using a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I have to create a class named Myset which includes methods like IsEmpty(), Insert(Object O) etc. I thought to use a Linked list of objects to implement the Myset class. But as I am new to Java, I am stuck with creating the object itself i.e. I am not clear even how to start with. I thought of something like this:

```
public class Myset {
    LinkedList<Object> LL = new LinkedList<Object>(); 
}
```

I further have to write a method: `public Myset Union(Myset a)`: Returns a set which is the union of the current set with the set a. This can be done by iterating through a, if the element at a particular index in a is not contained in LL then we add that element to LL. But how do I write this in a Java code? 
 PS: This is an assignment question and we aren't allowed to use Sets implementation.

Comment: Your question isn't _really_ about implementing a LinkedList. It's about implementing a Set _using_ a LinkedList. I have edited it for you.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and learn the Java coding standards.  You aren't following with your method names.  It'll come to grief.

Comment: So what is your specific question about this? You do not really expect us to solve the whole assignment for you, do you?

Comment: Study the Set class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.HTML) This alone should give you an idea of what to do.

Answer (score 5):

Some starting points.

You should either use "true" generics:

```
class MySet<T> {
  private final LinkedList<T> objects = new LinkedList<T>();
```

or leave generics completely out, like:

```
class MySet {
  private final LinkedList objects = new LinkedList();
```

You see, your solution

```
LinkedList<Object> LL = new LinkedList<Object>();
```

will allow that the user can store **any** kind of object in your set. So, first a String, then an Integer, and so on. Most likely, that is **not** what you had in mind. In general, collections in Java are about a **specific** sort of objects, like only Strings, or only Integer objects.

( side note: LL is a bad name for a field - so study java naming guide lines for that, too )

But there is even less sense in use `<Object>`. That is like using generics without using them at the same point.

And now, that you have a MySet class, you start one by one:

1. You add a constructor that allows instantiating an object of your class
2. You add methods (one by one!) that allow reasonable interaction with your class

Thing is: start slowly. Dont try to solve the big things upfront. Instead: just make sure that your class works as **Set**; so you can add things, you can check that they are in; and so on.

And only when all of these basic things work you should go forward and add  stuff like "union".

Comment: Actually use of `LinkedList<Object>` is quite viable, and better than the use of raw types (which is in the Java platform for nothing else than compatibility reasons). It means that the `List` should allow insertion of arbitrary objects.

Comment: It is true that `List<Object>` is wrongly used here... it's used in functions such as: `add(List<Object> list, Object o) ` if you want it to be able to work with any `List`, and in that case it's better than `add(List list, Object o)` since that could give you a `ClassCastException` at runtime. Which generics guarrantee won't happen. So you should specify that instead of saying it's like "using generics without using them at the same point". Upvoting...

Answer (score 2):

A linked list doesn't give you any benefit for a general set. You could simply use an object array, ArrayList, Vector etc. instead, as you would have to compare each element to another specific element anyway. If you insert an element, you have to make sure, there isn't already one in it (this is part of the mathematical definition of a set), just as you have to make this sure in unions, intersections and set differences. This means you have to implement comparability, so you should use the Comparable interface instead of Object, too.

Comment: Hint: writing easier-to-read answers (for example by using paragraphs) helps with getting upvotes.

Comment: thanks :) i normally do when answers get longer than this one.